# Entry point ("Item level" vs "Page level") and "Inline edit" vs "Edit page"

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, inline-edit

A project I'm currently working requires the user to be allowed to edit **only** certain items on the page. So the way the page is arranged now, a few items can be edited, and a few items aren't editable. I'm debating whether the entry points for the edit should be at a page level (doesn't inform which items are editable and which aren't) or specifying which items are editable and putting a button next to each item.

[image: Entry point: Page level vs. Item level]

The next part of my question is whether the entry points should lead to a new mass edit page or do inline editing. I'd prefer to do it inline if the entry point I go with is at item level. But due to a tech constraint currently, we can only allow for editing to happen one time. And that seems to be a risk with inline editing.

[image: Edit page vs Inline editing]

Would love your thoughts and comments! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The full page can be frustrating for the user, as he doesn't know what is editable and what is not before entering the edit mode.
but does give you the opportunity to disable the non-editable items and explain why they cannot be edited (with a tooltip or message)
also, If this was a form to start off with, I would expect to see the same form when editing it, so I wouldn't hide the non-editable things but disable them.

The inline edit can work, but it depends on the amount of items in the page and the order of those items. also I would ask "Why would the user want to edit the non-editable items?" and be clear why they can't.

Here is another idea, putting all the items in cards and making some cards editable and some not.[image]

[image]